# How to see css style on desktop (offline) and also on website (online)?

Tags: html, css, styles

I have a `style.css` and a html files.
When I upload them to the server I see the headlines in the style I want but on my desktop I don't.

Both of my files are on the desktop

On the `<head>` I have this line in my html file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
```

What can I do to connect the files and see the style applied when I'm offline working on my desktop?   and also online in my website

- i want to add i just removed the /  and it works offline on my desktop (just href="style.css") but not online  -  but i want to be able to see it both online and both offline ----  and online its not in the same file

**  edit : now i see that what works on both is if i put my spesific website adress  - than it works on both online and offline :

but if i will want to ever change my website adress it would be hard to change on each page thats why i want it to be  :  href="/style.css  and not the website adress

Answer (score 4):

If you are working locally without a webserver you need to link your css files like this:

```
<!-- Windows -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Path\to\File\main.css">

<!-- Linux & Stuff -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/file/main.css">
```

Additionally you could use the relative path to your file:

```
<!-- if it's in the same folder -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
<!-- if it's in the css folder -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
<!-- if it's in the parent folder -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../main.css">
```

Comment: hi thanks for reply before checing i want to say i just removed the /  and it works  -  but i want to be able to see it both online and both offline ----  and online its not in the same file

Comment: I edited my answer, you could use a relative path as well

Comment: sorry im really new to this -  the file is in the main folder on the server  - and in my computer all files are on desktop  

so what is the final thing i need to do to see it on both ?

Comment: The browser starts to search the file relative to the path of your html file, you should try to have the same environment on both systems

Comment: how i do that exactly ?

Comment: i mean what is the code to use if they are both on desktop ?

Comment: again :  href="/style.css" works on server  ..... and href="style.css"  works on desktop

Comment: with "/" you tell your browser to search in the root path of that connection, which (in the desktop case) will be the root of your whole filesystem. So you use just "style.css" to tell him he should look for the file in the same folder as he already is. And the other hand the server would find the "style.css" as well, as long as it is in the same directory as your html file.

Comment: yeah but in my server they are in different files and in my server in order to put it in the same folder i would have to make huge numbers of style.css files

Comment: so it seems i need to choose between the two and cant have both

Comment: **  edit : now i see that what works on both is if i put my spesific website adress  - than it works on both online and offline : 

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.mywebstiename.com/style.css">

but if i will want to ever change my website adress it would be hard to change on each page thats why i want it to be  :  href="/style.css  and not the website adress

Answer (score 0):

your question is still not clear, but generally, your question seems to be based on the linking of the style sheet with your HTML file to see the results of your code on your personal laptop and the server both. The best practice to do that is to maintain a file structure which keeps the project organized, for example, there is a folder named "main" which is my project folder which further contains your subfolders like CSS and js, and inside these folders, you should keep your CSS and js files respectively.
A simple project file structure is,

main
|
|-css
    |-style.css
|-js
    |-script.js
|-file.html

If you follow the file structure to link your files, you won't go wrong, it doesn't matter whether you are on your personal desktop or on the server.

Comment: but i have my style sheet in main  so it should work on both   -  i mean what is the difference  ---  if on desktop i put it in another folder names css  it will just make the link longer it wont be the same as my online link still

Answer (score 0):

One thing i understood is that when you are working locally you have html files and the css file on the desktop. First of all i would recommend you to make a new folder and copy all your related files whether it be html files, css files or js files in that folder. It is a better way to encapsulate all your project files in a single folder. 
Moving on to the css issue - you said that it works when you remove /. It works because since your files are all on desktop they are on same directory structure.

Enough for clarification I want you to follow these steps:-

1. First make a folder and copy your html files, css files and js files in it. Lets name the folder as website.
2. Create a folder named css inside the website folder. Copy all the css files in that css folder.
3. Inside your html files, inside the  write `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">` provided that the name of css file is style.css and you want to include this particular file in your html.

And regarding your online issue, I am not able to understand it. If you clarify a bit more i may be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Your files should have the same relative path on your desktop and server, so that you can use that same relative path for both. The relative path is based on the location of your HTML file in both.

If you have a folder on your desktop that has 2 files:

- index.html
- style.css

Inside of index.html, you'll reference your stylesheet using `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">`

If you have a folder on your desktop that has 1 file and 1 folder containing a file:

- index.html
- css/ (contains file: style.css)

Inside of index.html, you'll reference your stylesheet using `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">`

Since you said that `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">` works correctly on your server, that means that your HTML and CSS files are contained in the same parent folder. On your local, you need to make sure that the same is true. That parent folder can be located anywhere - Documents, Desktop, a random subfolder - but as long as it contains that HTML file and that CSS file (and neither of them are nested in another contained folder), that `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">` will work for both.

Note: You can change the folder structure of either server or desktop, or both - but the relative paths must match, so that your relative link works for both.

Answer (score 0):

give like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```